# Rails image_tag rotates image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am using Amazon's S3 for image storage with carrierwave and fog configured. The images seem to store correctly however when I have a 'portrait' image (smaller width than height) it is not displaying correctly, but rather rotating the image on its side.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

uploaders/image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  storage :fog

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type

  process :resize_to_limit => [420, 0]

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end

end
```

show.html.haml

```
= image_tag(@idea.image_attachments.first.image.url).to_s
```

image_attachment.rb

```
class ImageAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  attr_accessible :image, :description
  belongs_to :image_attachable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: It appears to be a problem with images that originate from the iPhone and have exif (orientation) data associated with them.

Comment: I have this exact problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

in the uploader.rb file, try

```
process :auto_orient 

def auto_orient
 manipulate! do |image|
   image.tap(&:auto_orient)
 end
end
```

it should fix it.

Comment: This solution does fix it for new uploads. I'm still looking for a solution for previous uploads, though I'm not sure I'll find one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of trying to resize_to_limit, instead create a version that you would like to conform to. For example, if you wanted all pictures to "intelligently" downsize to a square, you could do something like this

remove from uploader:

```
process :resize_to_limit => [420, 0]
```

add to uploader:

version :portrait do
     process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]
   end

this way, carrierwave will store the original image, and will then also respond to your call when you do something like this:

```
@idea.image_url(:portrait)
```

this is assuming that your Idea model mounts your ImageUploader and has all the other necessary stuff already configured.