# Images Rotating on Upload in Rails 5.2 Using AWS S3 and Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails 5.2 app in which I am using activerecord attachments to upload photos as attachments.

They upload fine, but come out rotated.  I have seen other Stack Overflow questions that deal with Paperclip uploads and this issue (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165217/rails-image-tag-rotates-image) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519160/exif-image-rotation-issue-using-carrierwave-and-rmagick-to-upload-to-s3)), but since Paperclip is depreciated with Rails 5.2 the initializer they say to fix is not present.

Can anyone figure out what's going wrong here?

My form is like this:

```
  <%= simple_form_for [@capsule, CapsuleItem.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :item_date %>
        <input placeholder="Date of Photograph" type="text" id="date" class="form-control datepicker"></input>
        <%= f.hidden_field :item_date, id: "dateHolder", class: "hiddenDateField" %>
      </div> <!-- form group -->
      <%= f.input :photo %>
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= f.input :caption %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :capsule %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions text-center">
      <%= f.button :submit, value: "Add Photo to Time Capsule", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

My controller `capsule_item#create` method is here:

```
  def create
    @capsule = Capsule.find(params[:capsule_id])
    @capsule_item = @capsule.capsule_items.build(capsule_item_params)
    @capsule_item.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @capsule_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @capsule, notice: 'Capsule item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @capsule_item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @capsule_capsule_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And my `CapsuleItem` model is like this:

```
class CapsuleItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :capsule
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

The image is being displayed like this:

```
<%= image_tag rails_blob_url(item.photo.variant(auto_orient: true)), class: "card-img-top" %>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is the same underlying issue as the duplicate. If using `capsule_item.photo.variant(auto_orient: true)` doesn't work then let me know I'll get this reopened.

Comment: @muistooshort Unfortunately, I'm using `<%= image_tag rails_blob_url(item.photo)" %>` to render the image, so adding `variant(auto_orient: true)` makes it throw up errors`

Comment: I've also tried putting it in the model, but haven't found a successful way to do so.

Comment: `image_tag item.photo.variant(auto_orient: true)` should do the trick.